# Can things make smells?

Tags: word-usage

I have read that things "produce" smells. Something creates a certain smell, is OK, I believe. I could not find "something makes a smell" during my online search, however. I wanted to say, "The milk in the refrigerator is off and making a strange smell in there." Can I?

Comment: I'd suggest: The bad smell of sour milk in the fridge, or sour milk smells in the fridge!! The milk in the fridge has gone off and smells sour!

Comment: Yes. Maybe this question belongs on http://ell.stackexchange.com?

Comment: This is where Googling skills need to be used. There was a lot of interference (unwanted hits) when I Googled "made a smell" (I guessed the past tense version would be more common); searching for "made a bad smell" and "made a foul smell" was more productive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say it makes a bad smell. You can say it "smells bad".  You could say "something smells good in here". You can say "you smell nice" to a lady friend. (But if you just say something "smells" you are saying that it smells bad).

In all of those cases, you are the one actually "smelling" the aroma/odor; but all are correctly idiomatic.

But it may be more common in America if something makes a bad smell, to say "it stinks".

(Of course, if it smells REALLY bad, you say it "reeks", or "is stinking up the place" or "stinks to high heaven")

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to bring to your notice about collocations. Collocations guide us to use a word with the right combination. Accordingly, the collocations for make are:

- make a difference
- make a mess
- make a mistake
- make a noise
- make an effort
- make furniture
- make money
- make progress
- make room
- make trouble

SOURCE: https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/collocations-lists.htm

MAKE (meaning):
In light-verb constructions "make" implies an active role by the subject, who causes something new to occur or come into existence from pre-existing material or a pre-existing situation or the normal course of events.

SOURCE: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Collocations_of_do,_have,_make,_and_take#make

As far as I know, the word 'make' is used only with the instigator that causes the effect on something.

As an example we say,

> "The medication makes me feel good"
>
> (Medication-instigator, effect-feel good, something (affected by the
>   instigator)-me)

We'd not say

"I make myself feel good"

So in your case, 
What you mean is

"The milk makes strange smell"

(instigator-milk, effect-strange smell, something-?)

It must be

> "The milk makes the refrigerator smell strange"
>
> (milk-instigator, effect-smell strange, something-refrigerator).

As to why we'd use **produce** for smell is:

There's no need for a dependent like something. 
The instigator and effect are enough.

> "The rotten vegetables produce an unpleasant smell"

But for **make**, we need the dependent -something too:

> "The rotten vegetables make the place smell unpleasant"

Comment: Sadly, you've missed the collocation / acceptable string "make a bad smell". Collocation lists are never comprehensive. And your "As far as I know, the word 'make' is used only with the instigator that causes the effect on something." is not accurate; when you 'make an effort' you're not giving rise to an effort, but to some result. When you 'make haste', no one sees haste being produced. When you 'make water', you're not actually creatiing it, just redistributing it. English is rarely nicely behaved.